# dispatch_queue and core data

Tags: multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I know that `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe but I want to execute my fetches and updates in the background. So I have questions on if I can do this.

I have one singleton that accesses the core data stuff so I wanted to create a serial dispatch_queue_t can execute all the requests in serial. Is this okay cause I am not sure if all the requests will be executed in the same thread but there will not be any concurrent operations since it is serial.

Comment: [Core Data **is** thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21941891/10673). The `NSManagedObjectContext` is just thread contained. The terminology is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need in creating serial `dispatch_queue_t` just trust `NSManagedObjectContext` to handle   it, just use `performBlock:` & `performBlockAndWait:`

```
    [context performBlock:^{
        // do fetches or updates here and do not worry about threads,
        // just make sure your context has a proper concurrencyType
    }];
```

Comment: To be clear, @dadougster is correct, you shouldn't pin an `NSManagedObjectContext` to a serial queue because the serial queue doesn't guarantee thread confinent.